What does "this" in "talked about this" refer to?
While trying to get home to save his father from impending death, Miles was
battling Miguel. Miguel was preventing him from doing so, fearing that saving
his father could cause anomalies to occur. Meanwhile, Peter Parker and Gwen
were trying to put Miguel away from Miles:

Peter Parker: Miguel, that's enough! This isn't what we talked about.

Miles surprised by hearing Miles's words:

Miles: You talked about this?

What does "this" in "about this" refer to?

The rest of the dialogue clarifies this:

Miles Morales : You talked about this? You knew? You- you all knew?
Gwen Stacy : I- I didn't know... how to tell you.

Miles is shocked that Gwen and his other friends knew that his father's death was something that supposed to happen.
